# is it possible to run a build step in Visual Studio Team Services irrespective of failure of a build step

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, msbuild-task, custom-build-step

I am running an automation build using visual studio team services and I am having a series of build steps. One of the build step ( and the last ) build step is to shut down all the VMs using powershell script.

This build step is executed if all the previous build step passes. But if any one of the build step fails, the subsequent build step and also last build step does not get executed.

Is there a way to execute the final build step irrespective of the other build step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check the "Always run" option of the step.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. You are my man Friday...Thanks once again. This works.